# проблемы с const char * как аргумента конструктора

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, конструктор

Добрый день. Делаю упражнение по С++ по книге Прата.
Столкнулся в коде:

```
#ifndef _PLORG_H
#define _PLORG_H


class Plorg
{
private:
    char name[20];
    int con_ind;
public:
    Plorg(char *);
    void change_con_ind(int);
    void show();
};

#endif
```

А это методы класса

```
#include "plorg.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

Plorg::Plorg(char *a)
{
    //strcpy(name, a);
    con_ind = 50;
}

void Plorg::change_con_ind(int a)
{
    con_ind = a;
}

void Plorg::show()
{
    std::cout << "Plorg name: " << name 
    << " Contentment index: " << con_ind << std::endl;
}
```

главный файл:

```
#include "plorg.h"

int main(void)
{
    char * a = "Bla!";
    Plorg top = Plorg(a);
    top.show();
    top.change_con_ind(32);
    top.show();
    Plorg bla = Plorg(a);// {"Frodo"};
    bla.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки GCC выдает такие:

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 plorg.cpp  ex10_7.cpp 
> plorg.cpp:5:1: error: prototype for ‘Plorg::Plorg(char*)’ does not match any in class ‘Plorg’
>  Plorg::Plorg(char *a)
>  ^
> plorg.h:5:7: error: candidates are: constexpr Plorg::Plorg(Plorg&&)
>  class Plorg
>        ^
> plorg.h:5:7: error:                 constexpr Plorg::Plorg(const Plorg&)
> plorg.h:11:2: error:                 Plorg::Plorg()
>   Plorg(char *);
>   ^
> ex10_7.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> ex10_7.cpp:6:13: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
>   char * a = "Bla!";
>          ^
> ex10_7.cpp:7:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Plorg::Plorg(char*&)’
>   Plorg top = Plorg(a);
>                  ^
> plorg.h:11:2: note: candidate: Plorg::Plorg()
>   Plorg(char *);
>   ^
> plorg.h:11:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
> plorg.h:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr Plorg::Plorg(const Plorg&)
>  class Plorg
>        ^
> plorg.h:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char*’ to ‘const Plorg&’
> plorg.h:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr Plorg::Plorg(Plorg&&)
> plorg.h:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char*’ to ‘Plorg&&’
> ex10_7.cpp:11:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Plorg::Plorg(char*&)’
>   Plorg bla = Plorg(a);// {"Frodo"};
>                  ^
> plorg.h:11:2: note: candidate: Plorg::Plorg()
>   Plorg(char *);
>   ^
> plorg.h:11:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
> plorg.h:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr Plorg::Plorg(const Plorg&)
>  class Plorg
>        ^
> plorg.h:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char*’ to ‘const Plorg&’
> plorg.h:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr Plorg::Plorg(Plorg&&)
> plorg.h:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char*’ to ‘Plorg&&’
>     ^
> ```

где ошибка и как исправить?

Я хочу по умолчанию сделать в конструкторе аргумент еще сделать Plorg::Plorg(const char * a = "Plorga") но что то это тоже не получается, но это вторая часть вопроса...

Comment: Вы бы дали не 2 реализации, а реализацию, объявление и использование...

Comment: Зачем два раза приведен один и тот же код? И где определение класса?

Comment: Не увидел. Извините. Исправил

Comment: Теперь добавьте код, где вы его используете - в котором эти ошибки выскакивают...

Comment: Добавил код и полный вывод ошибок

Comment: ...и все отлично компилируется.

Comment: @Ivan: Код, который вы привели, не может и не будет порождать именно таких ошибок. Так что в чем-то вы нас обманываете.

Comment: Мда. В убунту закрыл один терминал, открыл другой терминал и все отлично скомпилировалось. Видимо код должен настояться! Спасибо большое @AnT

Comment: еще попробовал с -std=c++11  выдает кучу ошибок, а без этого параметра все компилится нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта ошибка означает, что в классе вы не объявили конструктор с такой сигнатурой  как

```
Plorg(char*)
```

Или что в самом определении класса возникла ошибка компиляции.

Проверьте определение класса.

Что касается вашего второго вопроса, то вы можете данным образом объявить конструктор

```
Plorg(const char * a = "Plorga");
```

Однако в этом случае может возникнуть неоднозначность вызова конструктора, если в вашем классе также объявлен конструктор по умолчанию без параметров. То есть, фактически, у вас получится два конструктора по умолчанию. От какого-то из них придется избавиться.

EDIT: После того, как вы включили в свой вопрос содержание заголовка, то, очевидно, данный ваш заголовок не соответствует тому, какой использовался при компиляции, приведшей к ошибке компиляции, так как даже номера строк в сообщении об ошибке не совпадают с номерами строк в вашем заголовочном файле.  Возможно, что вы компилировали модуль, не сохранив перед этим изменения вашего заголовка в файле на диске.

Имейте в виду, что данное определение

```
char * a = "Bla!";
```

некорректное. В C++ строковые литералы имеют тип константных символьных массивов. Поэтому правильно будет записать

```
const char * a = "Bla!";
^^^^^
```

Соответственно и конструктор должен быть объявлен как

```
Plorg( const char * );
       ^^^^^
```

чтобы вы могли записать

```
Plorg top = Plorg(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените создание объекта

```
#include "plorg.h"

int main(void)
{
    char * a = "Bla!";
    Plorg top(a);
    top.show();
    top.change_con_ind(32);
    top.show();
    Plorg bla(a);// {"Frodo"};
    bla.show();
    return 0;
}
```